# Request did not provide the required two-way TLS certificate

Tags: apex

I was integrating ADP api, I got the access token but when i goes for integrating ADP api then got this error - **"message": "Request did not provide the required two-way TLS certificate"** I create a package keystore using Java Keystore (JKS) but after then getting this error -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <soapenv:Fault>
            <faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode>
            <faultstring>Policy Falsified</faultstring>
            <faultactor>http://essapi.es.oneadp.com/time/v2/workers/T9KSDWY5U/team-time-cards?$expand=dayEntries</faultactor>
            <detail>
                <l7:policyResult status="Assertion Falsified" xmlns:l7="http://www.layer7tech.com/ws/policy/fault"/>
            </detail>
        </soapenv:Fault>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Here is my code -

```
public class getAccessToken {
    public static void getToken() {
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        HttpResponse response = new HttpResponse();
        Http http = new Http();
        
        // Set the request URL
        String authEndpoint = 'https://accounts.adp.com/auth/oauth/v2/token';
        request.setEndpoint(authEndpoint);
        
        // Set the request method
        request.setMethod('POST');
        
        // Set the request headers
        request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        
        // Set the request body
        String payload = 'grant_type=client_credentials' +
            '&client_id=43bc9f4db-1a7134191f47' +
            '&client_secret=49651ff570b6baac';
        request.setBody(payload);
        
        StaticResource staticResourceAFHMutualSSLCert = [SELECT Body FROM StaticResource WHERE Name = 'AFHMutualSSLCert'];
        Blob AFHMutualSSLCertKeyBlob = staticResourceAFHMutualSSLCert.Body;
        
        // Convert the AFHMutualSSLCertKeyBlob to Base64-encoded string
        String AFHMutualSSLCertKeyBase64 = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(AFHMutualSSLCertKeyBlob);
        
        request.setClientCertificate(AFHMutualSSLCertKeyBase64,'afhboston123');
        //request.setClientCertificate('', '');
        
        system.debug('request: '+request);
        system.debug('request: '+request.getBody());
        
        // Send the request and get the response
        response = http.send(request);
        system.debug('response: '+response);
        // Parse the response
        if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) {
            // Successful response
            Map<String, Object> responseMap = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());
            String accessToken = (String) responseMap.get('access_token');
            System.debug('Access Token: ' + accessToken);
            
            //Now we will get the Team Timecards - 
            HttpRequest requestForTeamTimecards = new HttpRequest();
            HttpResponse responseOfTeamTimecards = new HttpResponse();
            Http httpReq = new Http();
            
            // Set the request URL
            requestForTeamTimecards.setEndpoint('https://api.adp.com/time/v2/workers/T9KSDWY5U/team-time-cards?$expand=dayEntries');
            
            // Set the request method
            requestForTeamTimecards.setMethod('GET');
            
            
            // Set the request headers
            requestForTeamTimecards.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
            requestForTeamTimecards.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            try {
                //system.debug('requestForTeamTimecards: '+requestForTeamTimecards);
                responseOfTeamTimecards = httpReq.send(requestForTeamTimecards);
                system.debug('Response: '+responseOfTeamTimecards.getBody());
            } catch (System.CalloutException e) {
                // Handle the exception
                System.debug('Callout error: ' + e.getMessage());
            }
            
        } else {
            // Error handling for failed request
            System.debug('Error: ' + response.getBody());
        }
    }
}
```